# Python C.Committ not being recognized in SQLlite, Error only showing at Exit after data input

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm new to Python and SQLite3. I've created a database and am attempting to create an add function from user input. The addition to the DB is successful and fully callable through the menu until you exit. When you use the exit method on the menu theres an error and then the data isnt saved to the DB.

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect("Adventure_Time.db")
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute ("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTs characters(
          first_name text,
          last_name text, 
          email_address text,
          phone_number int,
          street_address text,
          city_name text,
          state_name text,
          zipcode_number int)
        """)
conn.commit()

def display_menu():
    print("Welcome to the Adventure Time Database")
    print()
    print()
    print("list - List all of the Records")
    print("names - Show First and Last Names")
    print("show - All Cities  ")
    print("add- Add a Character to the Database")
    print("exit - Exit program")
    print()  

def add_charcter():
  c = conn.cursor()

  try:
    first_name = input("First Name: ")
    last_name = input("Last Name: ") 
    email_address = input("Email Address: ")
    phone_number = int (input("Telephone Number: "))
    street_address = input("Street Address: ")
    city_name = input("City: ")
    state_name = input("State: ")
    zipcode_number = int(input("Zipcode"))
    
    sql = """INSERT INTO characters(
          first_name,
          last_name, 
          email_address,
          phone_number,
          street_address,
          city_name,
          state_name,
          zipcode_number) 
          VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,? )
        """
    c.execute(sql, (first_name, last_name, email_address, phone_number, street_address,city_name, state_name,zipcode_number)) 
    c.committ()
    c.close 
    print("Record Submitted to Database")
   
  finally:
    main()

def main():
    display_menu()
    while True:         
        command = input("Command: ")
        if command == "list":
            list_characters()
        elif command == "names":
            names_characters()
        elif command == "show":
            show_contact()
        elif command =="add":
            add_charcter()
        elif command == "exit":
            break
        else:
            print("Not a valid command. Please try again.\n")
    conn.close()
    print("See you in the Nightosphere!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: You should add the error message you are getting to the question here.  It will make your problem much more solvable.  I see some logical flaws, but you should include your error message as the answer is problem there.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 116, in <module>
    main()
  File "main.py", line 106, in main
    add_charcter()
  File "main.py", line 88, in add_charcter
    conn.committ()
AttributeError: 'sqlite3.Connection' object has no attribute 'committ'

Comment: You misspelled `commit`.  You have two t's.

Comment: THANK YOU so much! I swear it's always the tiniest things. I end up straining looking through hundreds of lines of code and its something so simple. I appreciate your time and energy.

Comment: You should always read your error messages carefully.  The answers are usually there.

Answer (score 0):

```
  c = conn.cursor()
```

c is cursor object so you can not call `commit` on it.

you need to call `conn.commit()`

Comment: thank you so much for responding, when I changed it I still got the same error. The error happens after you have entered a user then enter exit.